# My LoadBalancer target group showing instance status unhelathy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have an AMI. I created one EC2 instance from that AMI and then added EC2 into the load balancer target group and the target group showed its status as healthy and it's working fine.

I again used the same AMI created a launch template and then created an auto-scaling group using that launch template. The ASG launched the EC2 instance in the same target group and now in the target group it is showing as unhealthy.

I am not able to figure out the problem because I used everything the same in both scenarios. But still, I am facing trouble. If anyone knows any solution to this problem, please mention it in the comment, it will be really helpful.

Comment: Given the lack of specific details in your question, nobody is going to be able to give you a clear answer. There are a lot of things you have to copy over from the single EC2 instance launch, to the ASG settings (security group, subnets, user-data, etc..). You need to look at the AWS console and compare every single setting in the working EC2 instance to the instance that was launched by the ASG and find the difference.